# Is there a blame/annotate for 'MKS Source Integrity'?

Tags: version-control, blame, mks-integrity

I am accessing some source code controlled on Windows via 'MKS Source Integrity' (a proprietary VCS, predecessor to 'MKS Integrity').

How can I find out in which revision particular lines of source code were last changed? The feature is variously called 'blame' or 'annotate' depending on the VCS.

**Update (21 May 2014):**

I'm using version 7.3e from 1999; I think MKS made large changes from ver 8 in 2000 onwards, so later versions bear little resemblance and the upgrade path is difficult.

Comment: It may be possible to export an MKS Source Integrity repo to Git; you can then run `git blame`. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1314218/827263

Answer (score 3):

There is a command called "view annotated revision" in the GUI, which provides a blame-like view of a particular file, including the commit ID, author, timestamp, etc for the most recent version of each line. You can also go to earlier revisions to see the annotation for the time when that revision was committed.
I know that this feature is in MKS Source Integrity 2009 and 10, but am not sure if it was in previous versions.

You might need to add it to the right-click menu in your sandbox view in the client, otherwise it can be accessed by right clicking on a node in the member-history graph for the file you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks, but its not in my version - 7.3e from 1999. MKS made big changes in 2000 with version 8, so products from then on probably bear little resemblance. I've updated the question to be clearer.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with that version, chances are that one of the later big changes added the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no functionality like blame in MKS.